# Setting Parent Component Modal Props From Other Child - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Firstly like to say that I am pretty new to React, however after scouring the internet for an answer to this one sadly nothing quite fits perfectly so here I am.

I have a component that holds a bootstrap modal which I then want to set the values of from another child and finally show the modal. While I could solve this problem by simply declaring the modal child inside the 2nd child component this would cause multiple renders of the modal for each child (generating a lot of redundant HTML code). So I want to declare the modal component in the parent and then somehow have its values set by the child when it is activated (I have created a basic version for ease of viewing):

```js
function DeleteModal(props)
{
    return (
        <div className="modal" id="div_DeleteModal">
            <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div className="modal-content">

                    <div className="modal-header">
                        <h4 className="modal-title text-center"><strong>Confirm Delete</strong></h4>
                        <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <div className="modal-body">
                        <p>You are about to delete this option</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" title='Please Confirm Delete' className="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

class ChildObj extends React.Component 
{

    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    DeleteVal(optionVal)
    {
        //Pass values to parent's "DeleteModal" props somehow?

        //Show Modal
        $('#div_DeleteModal').modal('show')
    }

    render() 
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <h4>{this.props.name}</h4>
                {this.props.delOptions.map(delOption =>
                    <button type='button' onClick={() => this.DeleteVal({delOption})}>Delete {delOption}</button>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

//Main App
class App extends React.Component 
{
    constructor(props) 
    {
        super(props);

        this.childObjs = [
            {'Name' : 'Obj A', 'DelOptions' : ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']},
            {'Name' : 'Obj B', 'DelOptions' : ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']},
            {'Name' : 'Obj C', 'DelOptions' : ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C']}
        ];
    }

    render()
    {
        return(
            <div>
                <DeleteModal />
                <div>
                    {this.childObjs.map(childObj =>
                        <ChildObj name={childObj.Name} delOptions={childObj.DelOptions}  />
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('ReactContent')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id='ReactContent'>
</div>
```

Many Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the running code! Your approach to create a single copy of Delete Dialog is very good. Here are few things that you can do:

**In React how to set and get data:** To set data inside, add properties to a component and to get data out of the component, use property which have names like that of event like `onChange`, `onClick` etc.

1. Add an `onClick` property to the `ChildObj` and call it like `this.props.onClick(<Child-object-id-for-parent-to-use>)`
2. In the parent i.e. `App` handle this click event, use the the `id` passed in above step to get the child object from the `childObjs` array.
3. In the parent have a state to open and close the dialog box and pass it to the `DeleteModal` as its property e.g. `open`. Internally `DeleteModal` will map this property to an `open` state to show and hide the modal box.
4. In the parent have another state to keep reference of `child object` and pass it to the `DeleteModal` as its another property, may be 'data'.  Internally `DeleteModal` will map this property to a `data` state to show values wherever you want to show in the modal box.
5. In the `DeleteModal` modal box, have an `onClose` property which you would want to call from the Close button of the dialog box. Parent (`App`) will handle this close event to clear the selected child `data` and `open` property. This step is more of cleaning the references.

Comment: Thanks, that go it! :)

Long story short, moving most the delete and modal show functionality to the top level "App" parent class was the way to go as you suggested.